# how to automatic generate local variables like IDEA in vim

Tags: vim

in IDEA, when we write

```
new StackOverflowQuestion()
```

there is a really convenience way to generate local variable:

[image]

then we get:

[image]

Is there such a vim plugin to help me automatic generate local variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with any snippet engine. I suggest you to check vim-snippets too (https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/).

This may not be exactly what you want, but check this line: https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/UltiSnips/java.snippets#L51

Assuming you are using ultisnips + vim-snippets:

```
Write o                   -> o
Press <Tab>               -> Object var = new Object();
Write Foo                 -> Foo var = new Foo(); // note: you write Foo once
Press <C-b> and write foo -> Foo foo = new Foo();
```

If you want something like `new Foo()` to get transformed into `Foo foo = new Foo()` you will have to write your own snippet, it shouldn't be that hard.